# Facebook Like Button wrong count, liked page shows as unliked on website and does not show up in Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have recently implemented the [Facebook Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

I have chosen some settings (for the HTML5 implementation) and facebook gave me the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=*my-app-id*";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-like"
     data-href="*http://my-domain.com/page/uri*"
     data-send="false"
     data-layout="button_count"
     data-width="50"
     data-show-faces="false"
></div>
```

I have implemented this code on my public website.

When I click the button it changes the button to the "liked" state and shows a dialog that I can use to post to my wall.

The wallpost works fine (and Facebook manages to extract the Open Graph meta tags from the page like image, title, url and so on...) when I refresh the page, the buttons shows up as one like, but when I visit the same url with another browser and facebook account the like button indicates that the page is **not** liked by anyone.

If I then check my https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) the like does not show up in the list.

I have also tried to use [Facebook's Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to make Facebook refresh the data for the url as I found on http://www.allwebmaster.com/2011/07/fix-facebook-like-button-not-working/ but that did not seem to help.

So the wallpost works but the like does not, why is that? What can I do to make it work?

Update: now I have a few likes on some of the pages but it does not correspond to the number of accounts that has liked that url...

Comment: Tirthen are you using some other facebook social plugin or any thing related to facebook on your web page?

Comment: I have a number of Open Graph meta tags like <meta property="og:locale" content="sv_SE" />, the fb-root and script tags first in the body tag and one like button div tag further down the page. Nothing more from Facebook, there is also a twitter share button but that should not be related...

Comment: As for as I have understood you have multiple facebook connect statements in your page. You have multiple script tags where you are connecting with facebook. Check this line `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=*my-app-id*";`

Comment: Yes but that line is the only one that includes any JavaScript's from facebook on the entire page.

Comment: has there been a resolution to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: It kind of seems like the cont started working more or less by itself.. I think it works good now without me having done anything more than before. So I don't really know what solved it, maybe it's just facebook's like system that's unreliable, maybe it needs time (some days/weeks) to start working for a new implementation...